# Thread to make a file in ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, excel

I'm trying to create a Report in Excel with a Table that could have 60000 records so I already have a function for doing that and it works, the problem is that when the table actually has this amount of records it last too much and the application dies. The solution I thought is putting that function in a Thread and run it background but it seems that the Thread begins to execute and then it just stops. Here is how I do it:

First I create a txt file and check if it was created, if it was I create the thread to create the Excel file. This function also edits the value of a hidden field when it's done, this is because when the thread starts I switch to another View in the multiview control and with a timmer I check when the values of the hidden field is changed for me to know that the file is done.

```
Protected Sub ButtonExcel2003_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonExcel2003.Click
'This function saves a config file
SaveConfigFile()
'Here I check if the file was created
If File.Exists(Server.MapPath("./Downloads/Configs.txt")) Then
        Try
            'FillExcel creates the excel file
            Dim t As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Me.FillExcel))
            t.Start()
            'I have a Multiview Control, I want that while the excel file is being created show the view number 2 that says "creating"
            Me.MultiView.ActiveViewIndex = 2
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Label2.Text = ex.Message
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox1.ShowMessage("Couldn't create the file")
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the FillExcel Method

```
Private Sub FillExcel()
    _IsProcessing = True

    Dim Celdas(13) As String
    Celdas(0) = "A"
    Celdas(1) = "B"
    Celdas(2) = "C"
    Celdas(3) = "D"
    Celdas(4) = "E"
    Celdas(5) = "F"
    Celdas(6) = "G"
    Celdas(7) = "H"
    Celdas(8) = "I"
    Celdas(9) = "J"
    Celdas(10) = "K"
    Celdas(11) = "L"
    Celdas(12) = "M"

    Try
        If (File.Exists(Me.sourcefile)) Then
            File.Delete(Me.sourcefile)
        End If
        'Template Name
        File.Copy(Me.CopySourceFile, Me.sourcefile)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me._FinExcel = -1
        Me._IsProcessing = False
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim strConex As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & Me.sourcefile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;ReadOnly=0;'"
    Dim conexion As New OleDbConnection(strConex)
    Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("", conexion)

    Try
        If (conexion.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then conexion.Open()

        If Me.IndexTipo = 0 And Me.Rows > 0 Then
            tipo = "SI"
        End If

        Dim dt As DataTable = getData(tipo, Periodo, 0, -1)

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            If dt.Rows.Count <= 65536 Then
                'Is 2003 version
                Dim cols = dt.Columns.Count - 1
                Dim i = 1
                Dim r As DataRow
                If i = 1 Then
                    For j As Integer = 0 To cols
                        cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE [Hoja1$" & Celdas(j) & (i).ToString & ":" & Celdas(j) & (i).ToString & "] SET F1='" & gridviewens.HeaderRow.Cells(j).Text & "'"
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Next
                End If
                For Each r In dt.Rows
                    i += 1
                    For j As Integer = 0 To cols
                        cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE [Hoja1$" & Celdas(j) & (i).ToString & ":" & Celdas(j) & (i).ToString & "] SET F1='" + r(j).ToString & "'"
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Next
                Next
                Me._FinExcel = 1
                Me._IsProcessing = False
            ElseIf dt.Rows.Count > 65536 Then
                If (conexion.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then conexion.Close()
                Me._FinExcel = 2
                Me._IsProcessing = False
            End If
        Else
            'No data to generate
            If (conexion.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then conexion.Close()
            Me._FinExcel = 0
            Me._IsProcessing = False
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        If (conexion.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then conexion.Close()
        Me._FinExcel = -1
        Me._IsProcessing = False
    End Try
    If (conexion.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then conexion.Close()

    _IsProcessing = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the `FillExcel` method do the actual task of generating the excel file?

Comment: FIllExcel copies a template into a directory and fills it with data

Comment: If you start any thread from an ASP.NET page, the page won't be dispatched until that thread is terminated. The asp.net page waits for all threads to join before dispatching the page. So in this case you don't rerally gain anything from working in a separate thread.

Comment: so would you give me some advice of how can i do to create the file without the asp page dies because it last too much?

Comment: Just wrote a long long answer for you. Hope this helps :)

Comment: 60000 records is not a report, that's a data export/extract. If you are getting near that number, you may be running into a row limit with Excel 2003 (65536 rows).

Comment: I thought so but I validate that when the number of rows is higher than 65536 the function returns the value 2 but that's not happening, also i test it with 400 records and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start thread from an ASP.NET page, they must complete before the page is dispatched. The page won't be dispatched until all threads started by the page are terminated. The asp.net page waits for all threads to join before dispatching the page. So in this case you don't really gain anything from working in a separate thread.

However, the good thing about asp.net is that we have ways to persist objects. e.g. Session, application, viewstate etc.

In such situations I usually create an object and persist it in a session variable. I let the object do all the work and just track its progress on the page via `UpdatePanel` etc. (or any other method).

Here is a skeleton of how to go about it. I'm sure you would be able to adapt this solution according to your needs. You would need to put your MultiView, error handling etc. yourself. I've omitted it here for the sake of keeping the answer to the point.

1. Put a ScriptManager, a Timer and an UpdatePanel on the aspx page. Add a Label and a Button in the UpdatePanel to track the progress. You can later customize the look and feel of UpdatePanel as per your needs.

   ```
   <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
           <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Enabled="false" Interval="1000" ></asp:Timer>
           <div>
               <h1>Long Running Task Demo</h1>
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                   <ContentTemplate>
                       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ProgressLabel" Text="Click the Button to write Excel file." />
                       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                   </ContentTemplate>
                   <Triggers>
                       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                   </Triggers>
               </asp:UpdatePanel>
           </div>
       </form>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Open the code-behind file and add the following code. (Notice that I have moved your `FillExcel` method in a separate class.)

   ```
   Public Class WebForm1
       Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

       Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
           ' create an object of our WriteExcelFileAsync class
           Dim AsyncExcelFileWriter As New WriteExcelFileAsync(Server.MapPath("./Downloads/Configs.txt"))
           AsyncExcelFileWriter.DoWork()

           ' save the object in session variable so that it can be retrieved back
           Session("AsyncExcelFileWriter") = AsyncExcelFileWriter

           ' enable the timer
           Timer1.Enabled = True
       End Sub

       Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
           ' retrieve the WriteExcelFileAsync object back from session variable
           Dim AsyncExcelFileWriter As WriteExcelFileAsync = Session("AsyncExcelFileWriter")

           If AsyncExcelFileWriter IsNot Nothing AndAlso AsyncExcelFileWriter.IsProcessing Then
               ' if it has not finished doing work (writing file) yet, show progress message..
               ' customize this as per your needs
               ProgressLabel.Text = "Writing file... Please wait...blah blah blah..."
           Else
               ' if the work is complete, show appropriate message
               ProgressLabel.Text = "Finished writing file."
               ' disable the timer
               Timer1.Enabled = False
               ' remove the object from memory and session variable
               If AsyncExcelFileWriter IsNot Nothing Then
                   AsyncExcelFileWriter = Nothing
                   Session.Remove("AsyncExcelFileWriter")
               End If
           End If
       End Sub
   End Class

   Public Class WriteExcelFileAsync
       Private SourceFile As String

       Private _IsProcessing As Boolean
       Public ReadOnly Property IsProcessing As Boolean
           Get
               Return _IsProcessing
           End Get
       End Property

       Public Sub New(sourceFile As String)
           Me.SourceFile = sourceFile
       End Sub

       Public Sub DoWork()
           Dim th As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf DoWorkTh)
           th.Start()
       End Sub

       Private Sub DoWorkTh()
           _IsProcessing = True
           FillExcel()
           _IsProcessing = False
       End Sub

       Private Sub FillExcel()

           'your FillExcel method...
           'write your file here

       End Sub

   End Class
   ```

Comment: Wow thank you! I'm going to implement it right now but it seems like it is going to solve my problem. Again, thanks

Comment: Just a question, do I need to configure something more in the app for working with Threads? I added one more variable into de WriteExcelFileAsync class you made, this variable is at the begining 0 and changes depending on how the FillExcel method ends but it keeps value 0, as if the thread begins but then stops

Comment: You don't need anything else for this method to work. You can however add whatever properties or variables you want to and it should not affect the working of this method. I'm getting a feeling that there is something bad with your `FillExcel` method. Try stepping thru it line by line and debugging it to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Just be sure that you don't mess around with the `_IsProcessing` variable. You need to set it to True when beginning processing and to False when ending processing, just as shown in the code I posted.

Comment: I'm going to post my FillExcel method, maybe there's something that kills the thread and I don't see it but in the DoWork method in your code, when I just call the FillExcel - not like a thread - it works. So please tell me if my method has something wrong.

Comment: You are issuing way too many UPDATE statements. Consider a batch level approach instead of cell level approach. And I'm not sure, but I guess after a certain point (after the last row in your present excel file) you need to start issuing INSERT statements instead of UPDATE statements.

Comment: Seeing how you are using the `_IsProcessing` flag, I updated my code above to show how to alienate the `_IsProcessing` variable from your `FillExcel` method by adding an intermediate method. So you can use your old `FillExcel` method as it it without worrying about the `_IsProcessing` flag.